# How to parse the heatmap output for the pose estimation tflite model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am starting with the pose estimation tflite model for getting keypoints on humans.

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview

I have started with fitting a single image or a person and invoking the model:

```py
img = cv.imread('photos\standing\\3.jpg')
img = tf.reshape(tf.image.resize(img, [257,257]), [1,257,257,3])
model = tf.lite.Interpreter('models\posenet_mobilenet_v1_100_257x257_multi_kpt_stripped.tflite')
model.allocate_tensors()
input_details = model.get_input_details()
output_details = model.get_output_details()
floating_model = input_details[0]['dtype'] == np.float32
if floating_model:
    img = (np.float32(img) - 127.5) / 127.5
model.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)
model.invoke()
output_data =  model.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])# o()
offset_data = model.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])
results = np.squeeze(output_data)
offsets_results = np.squeeze(offset_data)
print("output shape: {}".format(output_data.shape))
np.savez('sample3.npz', results, offsets_results)
```

but I am struggling with parsing the output correctly to get the coordinates/confidences of each body part. Does anyone have a python example for interpreting this models results? (for example: using them to map keypoints back to the original image)

My code (a snippet from a class which essentially takes the np array directly from the model output):

```py
def get_keypoints(self, data):
        height, width, num_keypoints = data.shape
        keypoints = []
        for keypoint in range(0, num_keypoints):
            maxval = data[0][0][keypoint]
            maxrow = 0
            maxcol = 0
            for row in range(0, width):
                for col in range(0,height):
                    if data[row][col][keypoint] > maxval:
                        maxrow = row
                        maxcol = col
                        maxval = data[row][col][keypoint]
            keypoints.append(KeyPoint(keypoint, maxrow, maxcol, maxval))
            # keypoints = [Keypoint(x,y,z) for x,y,z in ]
        return keypoints
def get_image_coordinates_from_keypoints(self, offsets):
        height, width, depth = (257,257,3)
        # [(x,y,confidence)]
        coords = [{ 'point': k.body_part,
                    'location': (k.x / (width - 1)*width + offsets[k.y][k.x][k.index],
                   k.y / (height - 1)*height + offsets[k.y][k.x][k.index]),
                    'confidence': k.confidence}
                 for k in self.keypoints]
        return coords
```

after matching the indexes to the parts my output is: 
[image]

Some of the coordinates here are negative, which can't be correct. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You may refer to this [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/posenet/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/posenet/PosenetActivity.kt) which processes the outputs of the PoseNet.

Comment: That file describes the processing of the keypoints after the heatmap has been processed, my next step. I'm currently trying to accurately process the heatmap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`import numpy as np`

For a pose estimation model which outputs a heatmap and offsets. The desired points can be obtained by:

1. Performing a sigmoid operation on the heatmap:

   `scores = sigmoid(heatmaps)`
2. Each keypoint of those pose is usually represented by a 2-D matrix, the maximum value in that matrix is related to where the model thinks that point is located in the input image. Use argmax2D to obtain the x and y index of that value in each matrix, the value itself represents the confidence value:

   `x,y = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(scores[:,:,keypointindex]), 
   scores[:,:,keypointindex].shape)`
   `confidences = scores[x,y,keypointindex]`
3. That x,y is used to find the corresponding offset vector for calculating the final location of the keypoint:

   `offset_vector = (offsets[y,x,keypointindex], offsets[y,x,num_keypoints+keypointindex])`
4. After you have obtained your keypoint coords and offsets you can calculate the final position of the keypoint by using ():

   `image_positions = np.add(np.array(heatmap_positions) * output_stride, offset_vectors)`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068651/tensorflow-determine-the-output-stride-of-a-pretrained-cnn-model/60071887#60071887) for determining how to get the output stride, if you don't already have it. The tflite pose estimation has an output stride of 32.

A function which takes output from that Pose Estimation model and outputs keypoints. Not including `KeyPoint` class

```py
def get_keypoints(self, heatmaps, offsets, output_stride=32):
        scores = sigmoid(heatmaps)
        num_keypoints = scores.shape[2]
        heatmap_positions = []
        offset_vectors = []
        confidences = []
        for ki in range(0, num_keypoints ):
            x,y = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(scores[:,:,ki]), scores[:,:,ki].shape)
            confidences.append(scores[x,y,ki])
            offset_vector = (offsets[y,x,ki], offsets[y,x,num_keypoints+ki])
            heatmap_positions.append((x,y))
            offset_vectors.append(offset_vector)
        image_positions = np.add(np.array(heatmap_positions) * output_stride, offset_vectors)
        keypoints = [KeyPoint(i, pos, confidences[i]) for i, pos in enumerate(image_positions)]
        return keypoints
```

Keypoint class:

```py
PARTS = {
    0: 'NOSE',
    1: 'LEFT_EYE',
    2: 'RIGHT_EYE',
    3: 'LEFT_EAR',
    4: 'RIGHT_EAR',
    5: 'LEFT_SHOULDER',
    6: 'RIGHT_SHOULDER',
    7: 'LEFT_ELBOW',
    8: 'RIGHT_ELBOW',
    9: 'LEFT_WRIST',
    10: 'RIGHT_WRIST',
    11: 'LEFT_HIP',
    12: 'RIGHT_HIP',
    13: 'LEFT_KNEE',
    14: 'RIGHT_KNEE',
    15: 'LEFT_ANKLE',
    16: 'RIGHT_ANKLE'
}

class KeyPoint():
    def __init__(self, index, pos, v):
        x, y = pos
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.index = index
        self.body_part = PARTS.get(index)
        self.confidence = v

    def point(self):
        return int(self.y), int(self.x)

    def to_string(self):
        return 'part: {} location: {} confidence: {}'.format(
            self.body_part, (self.x, self.y), self.confidence)
```

Comment: I am also stuck at interpreting the outputs of the pose estimation model. Can you please share what the KeyPoint class is doing?

Comment: I will edit my answer to include the keypoint class. but it essentially is just a struct for the values.

Comment: @yaffaity please note the updates: this code is also publicly hosted on my github https://github.com/ziggyjosh16/app-fall-detector/blob/master/person.py

Comment: I tried to run your model but the output is a set of random points it seems like here

Comment: The model does run decently well on some images with individual images but does not work on multiple people. I though the tfjs model runs on multiple pose estimation.

Even on some images with single person, sometimes the model fails completely. and just shows random points

Comment: The python tflite model does not work for multiple pose as I am aware. My example code only uses the pre-trained model, so I can't be held responsible for the accuracy (Unless you think there is something wrong with my implementation). You might gain better accuracy by retraining your own model with your own data.

Comment: Hey, so the implemetation is completely correct. However,the tflite model also works for multi pose estimation, as stated in the article, the decoding algorithm for single v/s multi pose is different.  https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5