# Tensorflow: Determine the output stride of a pretrained CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, pose-estimation

I have downloaded and am implementing a ML application using the [Tensorflow Lite Posenet Model](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/posenet_mobilenet_v1_100_257x257_multi_kpt_stripped.tflite). The output of this model is a heatmap, which is a part of CNN's I am new to.

One piece of information required to process the output is the "output stride". It is used to calculate the original coordinates of the keypoints found in the original image.

`keypointPositions = heatmapPositions * outputStride + offsetVectors`

But the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview) doesn't specify the output stride. Is there information or a way available in tensorflow I can use to get the output stride for this (any) pre-trained model?

- The input shape for an img is: `(257,257,3)`
- The output shape is: `(9,9,17)` (1 [9x9] heatmap for 17 different keypoints)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import json

model = tf.lite.Interpreter('models\posenet_mobilenet_v1_100_257x257_multi_kpt_stripped.tflite')
model.allocate_tensors()

with open('model_details.json', 'w') as outfile:
     info = dict(list(enumerate(model.get_tensor_details())))
     s = json.dumps(str(info))
     outfile.write(s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output stride can be obtained from the following equation:

`resolution = ((InputImageSize - 1) / OutputStride) + 1`

**Example**: An input image with a *width* of **225** pixels and an *output*
stride of **16** results in an output size of **15**

`15 = ((225 - 1) / 16) + 1`

For the tflite PoseNet model (resolution is 9):

`9 = ((257-1)/ x) + 1`
`x = 32` so the output stride is 32

[Source](https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5)

Comment: Can you little bit elaborate that what is the output stride in pose net , How it matters in Pose net model , How it is calculated and which number it should be ! . Kindly explain briefly ?

Comment: Please take a look at the attached source: In it, it explains: 

"this parameter affects the height and width of the layers in the neural network. At a high level, it affects the accuracy and speed of the pose estimation. The lower the value of the output stride the higher the accuracy but slower the speed, the higher the value the faster the speed but lower the accuracy. The best way to see the effect of the output stride on output quality is to play with the single-pose estimation demo."

Comment: Here is the demo: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html

Comment: I want to know that why it is happening , what is the reason inside the PoseNET ?